# Select and format two more characters. How?

Tags: css

```
<p><em>meta key here</em>:: meta value here</p>
```

```
i, em {
  color: red;
  font-size: 80%;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

I want to format the next two colon characters same as the <em> element.

I can format with CSS, but I can't add more HTML tags in the source.

Comment: The `:first-letter` pseudo class exists, but there is no way to select arbitrary amounts of characters beyond that, or in other places. I think there is no real way to do this, at most you could try to "fake it", by adding a pseudo element to the `em` itself, that will "cover" the following `::` with the same characters in a different color.

Comment: If you can't add more tags, the only way is using js

Comment: I can't do anything with the HTML side and I can't use js.

Comment: @IstvanRobotka You want to apply styles to `::`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot remove text with CSS so you are obliged to use hacks. In your case you can put a new `::` above the old one.

This is a specific solution to your specific case. It's not a generic solution and it won't work if your real example is different

```css
i, em {
  color: red;
  font-size: 80%;
  font-style: italic;
}

p em::after {
  content:"::" /* the new content */
}

em {
  position: relative; /* we need this to make the em above the next content */
  margin-right: -11px; /* this value depends on the font and you may need to change it */
  background: #fff; /* same as main background*/
}
```

```html
<p><em>meta key here</em>:: meta value here</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do what you are asking for without javascript is to define `::` as pseudo element's content

CSS has no way of selecting certain number of chars of certain element, you can only select first letter

There are more ways to go around this obviously, but you'd need to add more elements in html for this

So this is actually the only option you have

```css
i, em {
  color: red;
  font-size: 80%;
  font-style: italic;
}
em:after {
  content: '::';
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<p><em>meta key here</em> meta value here</p>
```

Comment: Yes, this I tried, but I can't touch in the HTML.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

CSS pseudo elements can solve this problem, here is the details of [Before pseudo element](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.php).

ps - I re-editthe solution with position and pseudo. it will create a overlay on actual colons(::). they will hide behind the new colons with css.

```css
i, em {
  color: red;
  font-size: 80%;
  font-style: italic;
  position: relative;
}

em::after {
  content: '::';
  color: red;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 900;
  position: absolute;
  right:-10px;
  top:0px;
  background:#ffffff;
}
```

```html
<p><em>meta key here</em>:: meta value here</p>
```

Comment: Yes, this I tried, but I can't touch in the HTML. Thank you for your help.

Comment: okay @IstvanRobotka, for this condition i re-edit the solution above. please check.